# Disassociate fork repo from parent in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, fork

We forked a repo in Azure, and we want to remove the original repo, but I am afraid that if I delete the original one, the forked one will also be deleted, is there a way to remove the fork link between those two repos?

Comment: `git remove remote $remote` in the local remote will remove the meta data regarding $remote from the repo without impacting the remote at all.  Where $remote is the name of the remote in the local repo.  That particular repo may exist under multiple names in the local repo, so perhaps you will need to do this multiple times.

Comment: Locally, the only remote I have is origin.

Comment: In my previous comment, "local remote" should be "local repository".  Apologies for any confusion.  `git remote remove origin` should do what you want and will not have any effect on the remote repository.  If you later change your mind, you can reverse that with `git remote add origin $url`

Comment: Git does not have forks. GitHub, Bitbucket, etc., do have forks, but the way they handle forks varies from one hosting site to another. [Azure's forks are documented here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops) Be careful to distinguish between *clone* (which is what Git has) and *fork*.

Comment: Based on that documentation page, there does not seem to be any way in Azure to "split" a fork from its parent. You may need to ask Microsoft what removing the parent will do, if anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove a git fork relationship in Azure Devops (VSTS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673550/remove-a-git-fork-relationship-in-azure-devops-vsts)

Comment: [Dissociate fork from upstream repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/3033#issuecomment-455615175)

Answer (score 1):

For our use case where we forked the original repo to stop using the original due to the department wanting to get all pipelines together we had the issue where while creating new PRs it shows as having a choice between new and forked-from repo. To remove the forked-from repo choice we disabled the original repo and then it doesn't appear as a choice anymore. Maybe that means we can also delete to original repo without impact, but given our uncertainty we're not willing to try this before experimenting with a test repo first...